# How can I shuffle only the first column of a table?

Tags: jquery, shuffle

I am using a function from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620677/jquery-shuffle-table-rows/12191498#12191498) to shuffle the rows of a table using jQuery. What I really want is to only shuffle the first column and leave the rest untouched, like this:

```
a b c d
e f g h
i j
```

To this:

```
e b c d
i f g h
a j
```

The function in [Rob W's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7620712/2359271) is:

> ```
> (function($){
>     //Shuffle all rows, while keeping the first column
>     //Requires: Shuffle
>  $.fn.shuffleRows = function(){
>      return this.each(function(){
>         var main = $(/table/i.test(this.tagName) ? this.tBodies[0] : this);
>         var firstElem = [], counter=0;
>         main.children().each(function(){
>              firstElem.push(this.firstChild);
>         });
>         main.shuffle();
>         main.children().each(function(){
>            this.insertBefore(firstElem[counter++], this.firstChild);
>         });
>      });
>    }
>   /* Shuffle is required */
>   $.fn.shuffle = function() {
>     return this.each(function(){
>       var items = $(this).children();
>       return (items.length)
>         ? $(this).html($.shuffle(items))
>         : this;
>     });
>   }
>
>   $.shuffle = function(arr) {
>     for(
>       var j, x, i = arr.length; i;
>       j = parseInt(Math.random() * i),
>       x = arr[--i], arr[i] = arr[j], arr[j] = x
>     );
>     return arr;
>   }
> })(jQuery)
> ```

But this does the opposite of what I want—it shuffles all rows *but* the first column. How can I change this so that it shuffles *only* the first column?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with:

```
var $firstCells = $("#tableIdHere tr td:first-child"),
    $copies = $firstCells.clone(true);

[].sort.call($copies, function() { return Math.random() - 0.5; });

$copies.each(function(i){
    $firstCells.eq(i).replaceWith(this);
});
```

That is, select all the first cells using the [`:first-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/), make a copy of them, and sort the copies randomly. Then loop through the (now randomised) copies and replace the originals with them.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/ceTmL/

P.S. Note that this technique will randomly sort any collection of table cells or elements if you just change the selector that creates the `$firstCells` jQuery object, e.g., if you change the selector to `"#tableIdHere tr"` it will randomly sort the *rows*.

UPDATE:

> *"I cannot understand what the* `[]` *does?"*

JavaScript arrays have a [`.sort()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) that allows you to pass in a custom sort comparison function like the one I used above that returns a random number between -0.5 and +0.5 to sort in random order. But jQuery objects are not arrays so you can't just say `$copies.sort(...)` on the `$copies` jQuery object. However, jQuery objects are *like* arrays in that they have numerically indexed elements and a `length` property, and some array methods (including `.sort()`) can be called on array-like objects if you use the [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or `.apply()` methods to call them. I could've said:

```
Array.prototype.sort.call($copies, ...
```

...but instead I went with the easier to type:

```
[].sort.call($copies, ...
```

...where `[]` is just an empty array that is there solely to provide access to the array `.sort()` method. The sort will be applied to the object that is the first parameter to `.call`, not to the empty array.

Comment: Thank You! Btw, I cannot understand what the [] does ?

Comment: Answer updated with a brief explanation of why `[].sort.call($copies,...)` sorts the `$copies` jQuery object. (Also, sorry if you wanted an answer that was a modified version of the code you linked to, but that code just seemed too long and complicated for what should be a reasonably simple operation so I ignored it.)